# How to improve this animation when mouse is over and out the effect is looped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using jquery to move a div. 
But there is something to improve

[image]

When mouse is close to the left border, the div constantly moves right and then moves left.
It's a normal behaviour because the area which is sensitive to the mouse is moving.
What do you suggest to improve this animation?

Here is my code and heres is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/MxcyT/)

```
var $content = $("#content");
var $main_container = $("#main_container");

    $content.hover(

    function () {
        $main_container.transition({
            x: '15px',
            y: '15px',
            width: '110px',
            height: '205px'
        }, 200);

    },

    function () {
        $main_container.transition({
            x: '0px',
            y: '0px',
            width: '95px',
            height: '190px'
        }, 200);

    });

});
```

I've also tried with mouseenter but same result :

```
$content.mouseenter(function() {
            $main_container.transition({ x: '15px', y: '15px', width: '205px', height: '205px' },200);
    }).mouseout(function() {
            $main_container.transition({ x: '0px', y: '0px', width: '190px', height: '190px' },200);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the container that's causing the transition is moving, it's obviously going to affect your hovers, especially if the container moves away from the mouse pointer. I would recommend moving an element that's housed inside a container, and let that container trigger the transition. This way, the container never moves, the hovers remain stable, and the animation will work correctly.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTjLc/), and here's the example (obviously you can make the container transparent, thus invisible):

***HTML:***

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mover"></div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#mover{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').hover(
        function(){
            $('#mover')
                .stop(false, false)
                .transition({x:50, y:50});
        },
        function(){
            $('#mover')
                .stop(false, false)
                .transition({x:0, y:0});
        }
    );
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Or a similar approach with `inline-block` and animating margin instead of coordinates:  http://jsfiddle.net/MTjLc/3/

Comment: Also a very elegant solution, thank you @JamesMontagne! I like it! :)

Comment: Chris, Really nice and simple solution (and @JamesMontagne your solution is original, you should post it) . Thanks, It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) this will prevent from looping animation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $content = $("#content");
    var $main_container = $("#main_container");

    $content.hover(

    function () {
        $main_container.stop().transition({
            x: '15px',
            y: '15px',
            width: '110px',
            height: '205px'
        }, 200);

    },

    function () {
        $main_container.stop().transition({
            x: '0px',
            y: '0px',
            width: '95px',
            height: '190px'
        }, 200);

    });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxcyT/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure it solves the issue because i can still see the looping animation.

Comment: When ever you hover the animation will happen.Here there is no delay(queue) by using `stop()` so there won't be looping

Comment: @sun You misunderstand the issue.  When your mouse is too close to the left side, the element moves out from under the cursor, triggering mouse out, it then moves back, triggering mouseover and that goes on until you move the mouse to a different position.  `stop` wont' help that.

Comment: Unfortunately I must agree with @JamesMontagne...I was able to replicate the original problem with the script above :/